# when concatenating two data frames an extra row is added

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am trying to concatenate two panda dataframes but unfortunately it's not working this is the following code:

```
train_df =pd.concat([x_train,y_train],axis =1 )

print(train_df)
```

y_train and x_train are of the same length and have the correct size and row indexes, I just wish to conctenate both of them like concatenating two matrices together.
My current output is the following:

```
       Age  Sex  HighChol   BMI  ...  PhysHlth  DiffWalk  HighBP  Diabetes
0     10.0  1.0       1.0  33.0  ...      30.0       0.0     1.0       NaN
1     10.0  1.0       0.0  21.0  ...      30.0       1.0     1.0       1.0
2      4.0  0.0       0.0  32.0  ...       7.0       0.0     0.0       1.0
3     11.0  1.0       1.0  35.0  ...      10.0       1.0     1.0       0.0
4     10.0  0.0       1.0  27.0  ...       0.0       0.0     1.0       1.0
...    ...  ...       ...   ...  ...       ...       ...     ...       ...
996    3.0  0.0       1.0  33.0  ...       0.0       0.0     0.0       0.0
997    9.0  0.0       1.0  41.0  ...      30.0       1.0     1.0       0.0
998   12.0  0.0       1.0  34.0  ...       0.0       0.0     1.0       1.0
999    6.0  0.0       0.0  31.0  ...       0.0       0.0     0.0       0.0
1000   NaN  NaN       NaN   NaN  ...       NaN       NaN     NaN       1.0
[1001 rows x 15 columns]
```

which for some reason seems to add a row of nan

edit:
apparently y_train is a series

Comment: Try resetting the index for both the dataframes while concatenating.

Comment: how is that done?

Answer (score 2):

You have a shift between `y_train` and `x_train` index: `x_train` index range is 0-999 while `y_train` is 1-1000.

`pd.concat` uses this index to align row. A workaround is:

```
train_df = x_train.copy()
train_df['Diabetes'] = y_train.values

# Or
train_df = pd.concat([x_train, y_train.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

But take care, you have to find why you have this shift.

Note: `y_train` is a `Series` whose the name is `Diabetes` that's why the last column of `train_df` is `Diabetes`.